# minus date and time by javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I have two times like : `"03/03/2011 07:41:00 pm"` and `"04/03/2011 08:41:00 pm"`

I want to make minus between it it's will be:

`"03/03/2011 07:41:00 pm" - "04/03/2011 08:41:00 pm" = h:m:s`

like this website

http://www.cobone.com/deals/dubai?lang=en

Comment: I cannot see the question here - perhaps because there is no question mark?

Comment: I add a JavaScript tag to the question. Later try to tag your question first with a name of programming language or specific software and after with some specific tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert the string into a Javascript Date object, you can do something like this:

```
//this time is 6 hours, 45 minutes, 30 seconds
var date0 = new Date(24330000);
var date1 = new Date(0);
var millisDifference = date0.getTime() - date1.getTime();
//this will alert "6:45:30"
alert(Math.floor(millisDifference / 3600000) + ":" + Math.floor((millisDifference % 3600000) / 60000) + ":" + Math.floor((millisDifference % 60000) / 1000));
```

Ideally though for parsing Strings to Dates and vice versa you want to be using a library like, for example, [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat).

Comment: Dear Melv I wont to minus time (now) from an other time